# Compile errors for different XCode versions

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, compilation

I am developing an application that should run on iOS versions >= 7.0 . I am currently testing my app using simulators. I find it very annoying to comment my code once i am switching to XCode 5 in order to test my application on iOS 7.
Is there any clean straight method that spares all the headache ? Is there any useful macro that allows to specify when to compile code and when not to ?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Errors that are related to methods that are available only on iOS 8 SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you have iOS 7.1 simulator in Downloads(Xcode>Preferences>Downloads)?

Comment: You mean if i download iOS 7 simulator then i will not have to test using XCode 5 ?

Comment: Yes I was using like that for my old project

Comment: @rokridi Yes, that's the entire reason why it is available for download, so you can build against the newer SDK and test against the older simulator runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on compiling the same code against older SDK versions that lack newer features that you are using, you should use the __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED macro from Availability.h.  Look at the header's comments for documentation, but the short of it is:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 80000
    // Do fallback path that does not depend on iOS features
#elif __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 8000
    if (check for availability of new feature at runtime)
        // Use new feature
    else 
        // Do fallback path that does not depend on iOS features
#else
    // Use new feature unconditionally
#endif
```

---

You can also download the iOS 7.1 simulator runtime from within Xcode 6 and run your apps against it (assuming the deployment target is set back to 7.1 or older).